# Resolving symlinks in lua

Tags: lua, symlink, symlink-traversal

I tried googling, but I found only additional packages handling this (which I would like to avoid for various reasons).

In Lua5.3, is there some way to resolve a symlink, possibly recursively, using just the standard library?

I'm looking for something equivalent to:

```
lua -lfs -e 'print(fs.realink("/proc/self/exe"))'
```

... only I don't have "fs" (and required "path") on my target.

Any way implementing this in pure lua using just the standard lib?

Comment: `path = io.popen('readlink "'..your_link..'"'):read()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: this works. If you make it an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua 5.3 i use...

```
cmd=function(cmd)
cmd=io.popen(cmd, 'r')
cmd = cmd:read('a+')
return cmd
end
```

...for storing output of external commands in a Lua variable. An example for using it...

```
erg=cmd('file /proc/self/exe|grep -o -E "[/a-z]{1,512}$"')
print(erg)
```

But `io.popen()` is not available on all Lua 5.3 environments for security reasons. So you have to check this before you can using it.